# How to change rpmbuild default directory form /root/rpmbuild directory to other

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, rhel, rpmbuild

I have to build a rpm package for some drivers.  I need to build the rpm from a .tar.gz archive.  The tar ball also contains the .spec file.  I have set up my rpmbuild environment as described here: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetupRpmBuildEnvironment

My directory structure is thus:

```
/home/rpmbuild
/home/rpmbuild/BUILD
/home/rpmbuild/RPMS
/home/rpmbuild/SOURCES
/home/rpmbuild/SPECS
/home/rpmbuild/SRPMS
```

The .tar.gz file contains the specfile and is placed in /home/rpmbuild/SOURCES

If I then navigate to that directory and run the following, the rpm package is built correctly, but is placed in /root/rpmbuild/RPMS instead of /home/rpmbuild/RPMS (where I expected it to be).

```
sudo rpmbuild -ta driver.tar.gz
```

I assume this is because I ran rpmbuild with sudo.  Am I thinking of this correctly?  Is there a way to direct it to build in /home/rpmbuild instead?

I know it is bad practice to use rpmbuild as root, but if I don't run it as root I run into many errors (not having permissions to access directories owned by root - like /tmp/orbit-root).  It seems like it would be much more difficult to change the permissions of each of these directories then to change them back.

Is this the correct way to go about this?  I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: NEVER run `rpmbuild` as `root`. You can *very easily* ruin your entire system.

Answer (score 15):

Don't create setup-tree for rpm with command as:

```
rpmdev-setuptree
```

Make rpm tree where you want to build the rpm with the command as given below:

```
mkdir -p rpmbuild/{BUILD,BUILDROOT,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
```

Now, copy the appropriate files in the folders as **specs** and **tar.gz** and run the following command in the rpmbuild directory:

```
rpmbuild --define "_topdir `pwd`" -v -ba SPECS/{*spec_file.specs*}
```

Answer (score 2):

the non-privileged user should have access to `BUILDROOT`. I would check `.rpmmacros` file inside `$HOME/rpmbuild` , it defines where is your top directory.

I have setup my `.rpmmacros` like this:

```
%packager YourName
%_topdir /home/build/rpmbuild 
%_tmppath /home/build/rpmbuild/tmp
```

Comment: That tmppath was key

Comment: Super! I wanted to build RPM on a container using gitlab runner. Adding .rpmmacros to home dir of user resolved rpm issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing non-root write permission on system directories,
then your `%install` scriptlet is not installing into `%{buildroot}`.

You will need to patch your build to install into `%{buildroot}`.

For autoconf generated Makefiles this is often done like

```
make DESTDIR=%{buildroot} ...
```

Answer (score -1):

To keep build files out of the default location, I specify a different build root by using the `--root` option to `rpmbuild`:

```
rpmbuild --root /home/rpmbuild -ta driver.tar.gz
```

It'll treat that directory as the total root and attempt to use `/home/rpmbuild/root/rpmbuild/{BUILDROOT,RPMS}` and `/home/rpmbuild/root/rpmbuild/var/tmp`.  The latter you may need to create before invoking the command. You can remove the `/root/` part of the name by prefixing the `rpmbuild` command with `HOME=""`.